# How can I create an object for each line in a text file, and assign attributes from each line respectively?

Tags: python-3.x, object

I am trying to read a text file and create an object for each line in that file.  I want to name the object iteratively, and assign the comma delimited information in each line to the attributes of the object.

```
class Site:

    def __init__(self, siteName, siteSerial):
    self.name = siteName
    self.serial = siteSerial


f = open('/path/to/sites.txt', 'r+')
lines = f.readlines()

for i in range(len(lines)):

    split = lines[i].split(',')
    st[i] = Site(split[0], split[1])
```

Each line in sites.txt reads like "Texas,111111111"

I want the objects to be named st0, st1, st2, st3, etc for each line in the txt file.
Is this possible?  It seems as though anyone who asks about this is told it's not the correct way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
st = []
with open('/path/to/sites.txt') as f:
    st.append(*Site(f.read().split(',')))
```

Comment: @jbilbs Do your lines always contain 2 parameters?

Comment: With this I am getting a Type Error: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'siteSerial'   Seems as though I am not getting both attributes passed.   Can I create the object and then assign the attributes?  Maybe that would be easier.

Comment: @jbilbs Please describe your issue with more details

Comment: Yes at this point they always contain exactly two parameters.

Comment: I basically just want to instantiate a Site object for each line in my sites.txt file.  Each line in that file contains two comma separated strings that I want to set as attributes of the class instance that the line creates.  So the code should read line 1, create an object called st1, and set st1.name to the first parameter and st1.serial to the second.  Then I want to do the same thing with the next line and st2, and the next st3, etc.